# ParseQuery for profile picture while displaying post

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am working on a sample app like Instagram in parse.com.Each post displays the profile picture(resized)of the uploader and the post photo.The user info is stored in a different class "_user" containing the profile picture in "profileimage" and the posts are stored in a different class "Posts".How to make a query to fetch them both (in a single query to reduce payload).The thing I have tried so far.I want to know what to add in my query.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("testing");
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0, ParseException arg1) {
            for(ParseObject obj:arg0){
                ParseFile pfile=obj.getParseFile("Image");
                coaching coach=new coaching();
                coach.setId(obj.getObjectId());
                coach.setName(obj.getString("Name"));
                coach.setPlace(obj.getString("Place"));
                coach.setImageurl(pfile.getUrl());
                array.add(coach);
            }
            listView.setAdapter(new  parseadapter());

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a relation, specifically a ParseRelation. You'll have to add a [Pointer](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-using-pointers) from your "Posts" class to your "Users" class. Do note that you add the user as a [Pointer](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-using-pointers) using their **objectId**. Something like:

[image]

Next you have to add the following code your query to include the Pointer object because by default the SDK does not. 
`query.include("postAuthor");  //your column name for pointer`

Lastly you have to fetch the ParseObject containing the User data separately (in your loop)

```
ParseObject author = obj.getParseObject("postAuthor");   // column name for pointer
ParseFile authorPicture = author.getParseFile("profileimage");    // column user profile picture

authorPicture.getUrl();   // profile picture URL
author.getString("name");    // name of the user
```

Consider fetching the name of the user who posted* as I have above, this is a better database design and will correspond to changes made to the name of a user.

I hope this helps you and others stuck in similar situations. [You can read more about ParseRelation here.](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations)

Comment: Thanks a lot to @Aashir.But will this design increase the number of requests I make to the Parse server ? If I am using the free version then I am allowed to make only 30 requests per sec .Will it exceed the limit.Will the entire thing be regarded as one query or the number of information extracted from these objects ? Once again though thanks for the help.

Comment: 1 query like this = 1 request to the server. So it should decrease the number of requests made by each user. I'm using the free version too, haven't run into any issues so far and you're welcome.